Webpacker compile very slow with Docker
We have a rails 6 application that we just dockerized a few days ago (for development environment for now). We had some issues with the image we managed to fix and now the whole application runs smoothly and everything works fine with Docker.
The only issue we have is that now the webpacker compilation takes way too much time. It was already taking maybe 30s before using Docker, but now it can take up to 5 minutes, minimum 3.
We tried caching the packs folder with the help of a volume:
- ./public/packs:/app_name/public/packs:cached
But it seems it didn't change anything.
Do we have other solutions?

Mounting volume is know to be slow. If you want to compile things, compile them on a non-mounted directory. Or investigate compose watch: https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/

As @β.εηοιτ.βε mentions, for development you could use a volume mounted locally (directly on your file system).
Following you can find an example, with the addition of using a combination of approaches, considering docker compose and a Dockerfile to take advantage of multi-stage (keep in mind I'm proposing a generic solution):
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'

services:
  api: # or whatever name you use
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      # use just the development stage
      target: development
    command: <command to start in dev mode>
    expose:
      - ${PORT}
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      # use the local folder mapped to `/app` in container volume
      - .:/app
      - <directory_you_want_to_include_in_volume>:/app/<target_in_volume>

volumes:
  <directory_you_want_to_include_in_volume>:
    driver: local

Dockerfile
FROM <your_image> as development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy source files
COPY . .

# Install with options as needed
RUN bundle install 

# Build API
RUN <any command to build/bundle your app>

# here the development build will stop, 
# and the start command of the docker compose file will take care.

FROM <your_image> as production

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy necessary files to run the app
COPY --from=development /app/<whatever_needed> ./

# Install only production dependencies
RUN <specific_production_bundler>

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails"]

